# What kind of knapsack analogue is this? Assembling an optimal team

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

**Definition of Team**

A team consists of a group of players.  Each player has a position and the team must consist of a given number at each position.  For instance in football, there might be 1 QB, 2 WR, 2 RB, 1 TE, and 5 OL.

**Definition of Optimal Team**

Each player has both a contribution and a price.  An optimal team maximizes the contribution while staying under a maximal price (a salary cap) yet *still* filling every role.  Again in terms of football, this might mean you *must* take *exactly* 1 QB, 3 WR, 2 RB, and 1 TE.

**My Problem**

The number of players I need to consider is not particularly large.  The team I attempt to build consists of 1 QB, 3 WR, 2RB, and 1 TE for which there were were 20 QBs, 97 WRs, 60 RBs, and 29 TEs (so 206 players in all).  If it were simply to find the highest value group staying under a certain price, then this would exactly be the 0/1 knapsack problem.

Now lets say I needed to find the best group of exactly 7 players (staying under a total price).  This would make this very similar to the multi-dimensional knapsack problem because each player can be given a weight of 1 and so this group weight would have to be <= 7 *and* the price should stay under a maximum price.  However, the requisite that it be *exactly* 7 players complicates things.  It's quite possible that if you choose fewer players, you can get a higher value than can be achieved with *exactly* 7 players.

And the final constraint complicates things further.  Again it could be stated as being similar to the multi-dimensional knapsack problem since you could assign 4 dimensions for each position and then the multi-dimensional weight would determine the position of the player, e.g. `p(12, $10000, 0, 1,0,0)` could represent a player with value 12; price $10,000; and is a WR.  Then the constraint would be that the final weight of the team must be `<= w(MAX_PRICE, 1, 3, 2, 1)`.  Except again, it should be *exactly* equal to the weights determining who is on the team, not less than or equal to those limits.

**So What's My Question**

My question is still what type of problem is this and whether or not there are "standard" algorithms for solving such problems.  It seems like this is not some strange oddball problem, it seems very similar to a knapsack problem and thus I assume has been studied.  I am looking for information about this problem (firstly, what is it called) and/or research papers covering this type of problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for a name that describes your problem, a good algorithm for certain input sizes, etc.?

Comment: @arghbleargh Yes, I am looking for a name that describes this type of problem.  Assuming the problem has been named, then I can find a good algorithm (or maybe no good one exists).  This is clearly some variant of the "most general knapsack problem" where we place items into bins and there are "numerous" constraints on what a valid list may be.  I am asking 1) if there is such a generalization where can I find information on it or 2) if not, is this situation a combination or even a special case of known generalizations to the knapsack problem?  Hopefully that clarifies???

Comment: @arghbleargh At the bottom I try to speculate on possible "known" knapsack problems this might be...if that helps at all, i.e. is it a **[multi-objective knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-objective_knapsack_problem)** (I think maybe, but I'm not sure), a **[multiple knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem)** (I don't think it is), a **[bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)** (I don't think it is), or a combination of those (or other) methods (I'm not sure)?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. You've posted the assignment.

Comment: @KenWhite I seriously doubt this is an assignment...but if so that must mean there is an "easy" solution to it--which I would like to be made aware of (a simple link would do if it explained this problem or equivalent of this problem).  I included the work I had done prior to this, it was included in the **bolded** section labeled by **What Have I Done?**.  I _do_ have a solution, but it is rather complicated and makes me wonder whether or not there are previously known algorithms for this type of problem.

Comment: "I seriously doubt this is an assignment"? Right. As the poster of the question, you don't know if it's an assignment or not? What I have done should include some actual code making an effort. An effort solve world hunger isn't "I googled it".

Comment: @KenWhite I don't understand what is unclear about my question.  The question is in the question box: _"What kind of knapsack analogue is this?"_  Is it a 0/1 knapsack problem, a bounded knapsack problem, an unbounded knapsack problem, a multi-objective knapsack problem, a multi-dimensional knapsack problem, multiple knapsack problem, a bin packing problem, etc.  At no point did I ever ask about how to solve this problem; I only described it and explained what I had done attempting to _classify_ it.  I explained, in my question, that I do not think it fits into any of the above categories.

Comment: I've voted to reopen your question after your edit. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Jared:  Look at it from our point of view. We're flooded(particularly at this time of year and in the spring) with thousands and thousands of homework dumps by posters trying to get their degree without any work. If it walks like and talks like, chances are pretty good it is one. I voted to reopen after you edited to make it more clear that it was not a homework question. There's not much more I can do; removing the vote is the only recourse I have available. If you don't want the same mistake made in the future, take more time to make your question clear.

Comment: I'm sorry...I have to laugh at this post...I detailed my algorithm after this got closed for being a "homework question", then madly deleted it...then did several other deletes...and now this is getting revised to something that wasn't my full algorithm...lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a variant of the pseudo-polynomial knapsack approximation for this, assuming that no player is worth hiring for each of two possible player classes. Scale and round either the worth or the cost values to turn them into integers. Then go over the player classes one by one. At each stage you keep track of either the highest worth achievable for each possible cost, or the lowest cost achievable for each possible worth, depending on whether you have scaled and rounded the cost or the worth - by scaling and rounding you make sure that there is only a manageable number of different costs or worth.

You start off with 0 cost and zero worth. At the end of each stage you know the highest worth achievable for each possible cost, or the lowest cost achievable for each possible worth. By considering all the options for that player class, work out new highest worth/lowest cost for a team that includes the specified number of players for that class. At the end you have the highest worth for each cost or lowest cost for each worth, and your answer is the one which is just affordable. Given knowledge of that answer, you can track back, using information stored previously, to work out the entire team choice.